# Minecraft kill all players except a certain player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a house, with a security system, where only I am allowed. My command block is supposed to kill all players except me, but I can't find what command to use. I've tried `/kill @a[name=!<My username]`, but it doesn't work. What is the actual command

Comment: The command OP suggested seems like the most logical one that I could think of. Does anybody know why it doesn't work?

Comment: `/kill @a[name=!bearb001]` works fine for me, it doesn't kill me. I didn't test it with multiple players though, but `/kill @e[name=!bearb001]` killed 140 entities, I survived that command. May I ask what your username is? If you don't want to tell it publicly, then does your name have anything special? Maybe white space, or some unusual characters like ö, ß, Å, etc.

Comment: @bearb001 I don't think those characters can be included in usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scoreboard teams feature.

First, create a team: `/scoreboard teams add <name>`
Then, add the player you don't want to kill to the team: `/scoreboard teams join <team> <player>`
Finally, kill the everyone apart from the team: `/kill @a[team=!<team name>]`

So if you wanted to kill everyone except for team Arqade which had you in it, you would do:
`/scoreboard teams add Arqade`
`/scoreboard teams join Arqade <Your Username>`
`/kill @a[team=!Arqade]`
Replacing '`<Your Username>`' with your in-game Minecraft username.

If you want to remove someone from a team, you do `/scoreboard teams leave <player>`

Answer (score 3):

[EmeraldEye](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/231994/emeraldeye)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/356430/171580) works, but it removes all information on what team someone was if teams were used already. You could instead use tags, but there is an even easier way, in one command:

```
/execute at <player_name> as @a unless entity @s[distance=0] run kill @s
```

This is easy to write, but hard to understand. What this does is first shifting the execution position to the player you want to not kill, but still executing **as** whatever executes the command (a command block for example). Then it changes the execution context to be done by all players, without changing the position where it executes. It also splits up all further parts of the command, so that they run once per player. Then it checks if the selected player has distance 0 from the execution position (which is still the one player's position that you don't want to kill) and if they do not have distance 0, they get killed.
The advantage of checking for distance 0 and negating the selection is that it also selects people in other dimensions, unlike something like `if entity @s[distance=0.001..]` would do.

Keep in mind that this command will not kill players that are on the exact same position as the player you don't want to kill. But that can only happen in rare situations like respawning, dismounting a minecart at a fixed position, teleporting, … and then not moving before the other player does the same.

Comment: You are right. This answer is much easier to write and it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

you could make something like:
give everyone who shouldn't be killed the tag `dontkillme` via
`/tag <playername> add dontkillme`
and then run
`/kill @a[tag=!dontkillme]`
then every player who doesn't have the `dontkillme` tag will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

`/kill @e[type=Player,name=!playerName]` should do the trick

Comment: Even simpler, `@p[name=!<playername>]` seems to work fine in Minecraft 1.20.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use Doing /kill @e[type=!Player] kill all entities non players.And run it a second time to delete dropped item entities.

Comment: I think the person who asked the question wanted to kill all players except for himself. I don't think he wanted to kill all entities except for players.